# See what git fetch displayed last time

Tags: git

After I have fetched the remote data (`git-fetch`), git is friendly enough to tell me the SHAs on each branch, `old..new`, but if I work a lot in the console, I may lose them.

How to display them again?

Of course I could save the output to a file or remember it. These are no options for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

From the comments:

To get what ***just*** changed on all remote branches, do

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes | 
    while read ref type name
    do 
        echo ----- $name
        git log --oneline "$name@{1}..$name@{0}"
    done
```

Typical output:

```
----- refs/remotes/sehe.nl/stable
warning: Log for 'refs/remotes/sehe.nl/stable' only has 1 entries.
----- refs/remotes/sehe.nl/testing
4934e92 reviewed INSTALL file as per #1331
----- refs/remotes/sehe.nl/unstable
----- refs/remotes/sehe.nl/xattrs
warning: Log for 'refs/remotes/sehe.nl/xattrs' only has 1 entries.
----- refs/remotes/tobey/maint
6215be7 reviewed INSTALL file as per #1331
----- refs/remotes/tobey/maint-0.6.9
warning: Log for 'refs/remotes/tobey/maint-0.6.9' only has 1 entries.
----- refs/remotes/tobey/master
warning: Log for 'refs/remotes/tobey/master' only has 1 entries.
----- refs/remotes/tobey/testing
4934e92 reviewed INSTALL file as per #1331
```

Note that, `unstable` just had *no reachable commits* between @{1}..@{0}, the branches with warnings *had no prior ref value* in the log.

> #### *Bonus*
>
> I prefer to tweak the log as well:
>
> ```
>      git log --oneline --graph --left-right --cherry-pick \
>             "$name@{1}...$name@{0}"
> ```
>
> (*note the extra dot in ... (!)*)
>
> This will show the merge directions, and also show non-linear commit differences; I.e. it works well in showing differences in refs that may have been *force-pushed* (or pulled)

---

To get reflog info for all branches, simply

```
git log -g --oneline --branches
```

You'll get output similar to:

```
4934e92 testing@{0}: commit: reviewed INSTALL file as per #1331
6215be7 maint@{0}: commit: reviewed INSTALL file as per #1331
1e5e121 emmanuel@{0}: rebase finished: refs/heads/emmanuel onto f6e2c6c3f9cec0ccf7d96d3edb92f806587adcbc
7b326b9 emmanuel@{1}: branch: Created from rainemu/master e96783e compress@{0}: rainemu/compress: updating HEAD
ff19004 compress@{1}: rebase finished: refs/heads/compress onto f6e2c6c3f9cec0ccf7d96d3edb92f806587adcbc
f6e2c6c unstable@{0}: rebase -i (abort): updating HEAD
6b8f506 unstable@{1}: commit (merge): Merge remote branch 'rainemu/master' into unstable 5327c2f unstable@{2}: merge rainemu/master: Merge made by recursive.
f6e2c6c unstable@{3}: merge emmanuel: Fast-forward
f45ff54 unstable@{4}: merge rainemu/master: Merge made by recursive.
e23fc0b maint@{1}: commit: fix scons warnings dd52720 master-lucid@{0}: commit: lucid 1fb30cf testing@{1}: commit: fix missing split on environment CFLAG
aac7936 unstable@{5}: pull rainemu master: Merge made by recursive.
2c01d7f unstable@{6}: branch: Created from sehe.nl/unstable 927ad7a testing@{2}: branch: Created from sehe.nl/testing
3b32fa7 maint@{2}: branch: Created from sehe.nl/maint 6eaa64f maint-0.6.9@{0}: branch: Created from sehe.nl/maint-0.6.9
```

Comment: Thanks. And how could I work out which is the HEAD of every branch, so I can quickly do `git log old..new`? `reflog` seems to just dump out everything.

Comment: erm... wouldn't the HEAD be synonymous to both `branch@{0}` and `branch` and `refs/heads/branch` ([man git-rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html)) ?

Comment: I mean "normally" i have HEAD and FETCH_HEAD. How can I work out which is which? `branch@{0}` is FETCH_HEAD I suppose.

Comment: Given my previous comment a bit more space by integrating it into the answer. Cheers

Comment: Omg you rock, I would +42 this if I could. I have +1'ed some other good answers of you instead.

Comment: @Flavius: I appreciate the gesture! However, for your info: next time, you'll want to _just say thanks_: the reputation system is not intended for mutual confirmation and back-patting... Case in point: I think you upvoted me 14 times (?) and that is quite enough to trigger the 'fraud detection' algorithm of SO: I received -340 rep overnight (apparently it retroactively decided there were other 'suspect' votes, or there is a penalty system involved?) **No problem**, just so you know that in the future

Answer (score 1):

`git reflog show origin/master` seems to work; run it for each branch I guess.  I don't think there is a single reflog command to pull data for all branches

Comment: See my answer for reflog across all branches